# Should auto notifications include greeting / salutations?

Tags: email, copywriting, notification

I have built a template to follow when creating auto notifications from an internal system (for employees only), I had been advocating for including the greeting `Hello <Name>`.

Currently the auto notifications say `Dear <Name>`, which I think is very old fashioned.

However, now I am questioning whether we need a greeting at all.  It's obviously an auto generated email and there are rules as to when you would receive it (i.e. only if it is a status update or for an action – not FYI purposes).

Is the greeting superfluous given we are all very busy and just want to know what we need to do?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I don't think it matters much what greeting you use as long as it's consistent with the tone elsewhere in the system.  If you can give us a bit more context about who is communicating with whom using this system, and how they usually communicate, you might find you've answered your own question.

Comment: Thanks - the problem is that there is little consistency at present so looking to introduce best practice guidelines.  The auto emails will come from a HR system to employees, however employees will get a mix of these auto messages and messages from the operations team.  The question is really around if you receive an auto response that appears to be from a system, is it expected / standard to have a greeting i.e. the system to be saying 'hi'?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the purpose of the message:

For a message that conveys factual information such as an acknowledgement of submission or system update I would say you could go with with `John Doe,` or no name at all.

If it is something like a seasonal greeting then `Hi John,` or `Hello John Doe,` would be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the tone of the message itself.  If purely informational and somewhat formal, I would say go with simply `John Doe,`.  However, if the tone is light and informal, I'd go with `Hello Mr. Doe,`.

Another thing to consider is whether these messages are intended to seem as if they are being written by humans or simply a transfer of information from computer to human.  If the latter, no greeting is warranted, if the former, it would be just as appropriate as in a message from another human.